# If integrals are the same over every measurable set, then two functions are equal a.e.

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},P)$ be a probability space and $f,g(\Omega,\mathscr{F})\rightarrow [0,\infty]$ be measurable functions.

If $\int_E f dP=\int_E g dP$ for every $E$, how do I prove that $f=g$ $P$-a.e.?

If $f,g$ do not assume the value $\infty$, this is obvious by considering $\int_E f-gdP =0$. However, if this is not the case, since $f-g$ may not be defined, usual argument cannot be applied.

Comment: Can you clarify what kinds values the functions $f,g$ take, and what it means for $f,g$ to be measurable? I know what these mean if $f,g$ are real valued functions, but you seem to have something else in mind, because $\infty$ is not a real number.

Comment: @LeeMosher I edited it and answered the question myself below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $q,t$ be nonnegative rationals such that $t<q$.

Note that $$qP(f>q,g\leq t)=\int q\chi_{f>q,g\leq t} dP \leq \int f \chi_{f>q,g\leq t}= \int g \chi_{f>q,g\leq t} \leq \int t\chi_{f>q,g\leq t} = tP(f>q,g\leq t)$$.

Hence, it must be $P(f>q,g\leq t)=0$. (Note that finiteness of $P$ is used here)

This means that $P(f>g)=0$, and analogously we have $P(g>f)=0$. Hence, $P(f=g)=1$.

Comment: (+1) I know that you assume that your measure is a probability measure in the question but here you only use that assumption in a very minor way. It'd be enough to see that if $P(f > q, g \leq t) > 0$  then there is $A \subseteq \{f > q, g \leq t\}$ of finite positive measure. For this, semifiniteness (and hence $\sigma$-finiteness) is enough. Semifiniteness is very often a requirement to avoid pathological examples and is satisfied by most every measure space you'll ever work with.